# Finding a map from one group representation to another

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Suppose I have a unitary $|G|$-dimensional group representation $D(g)$ of a group $G$. I want to find all $|G|\times d$ matrices $X$ such that
$$\forall g\in G, \qquad [D(g), XX^\dagger] = 0$$
subject to
$$X^\dagger X = I.$$
Finding this $X$ then gives us a mapping from a $|G|$-dimensional representation $D(g)$ to a $d$-dimensional representation $U(g)$, where
$$U(g) = X^\dagger D(g) X.$$

Is there a way for me to find such $X$ that doesn't rely on numerical methods? If it helps, the representation $D(g)$ I'm working on is the following adjoint representation:
$$D(g)\mathbf{g_i} = \mathbf{g} \mathbf{g_{i}}\mathbf{g^{-1}} = \mathbf{g_{j}}D_{ji}(g)$$